# Multiplying ee.image by a number in Google earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to process some Air surface temperature data to calculate temperature seasonality for 2013-2015. The formula I'm using is just the standard deviation of monthly temperature for each year X 100 (and then averaging my 3 years)

This is the code I'm using, but I think it is incorrect to use .multiply(100) because it's combining an ee.image with a java object? I'm not sure how to do it otherwise

```js
var ASTmonthcollection2015 = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([meanASTjan15, meanASTfeb15, meanASTmar15, meanASTapr15, meanASTmay15, meanASTjune15, meanASTjuly15, meanASTaug15, meanASTsep15, meanASToct15, meanASTnov15, meanASTdec15])

var AST2015seas = ASTmonthcollection2015.reduce(ee.Reducer.std_dev())

var AST2015seasclip = AST2015seas.clip(southafrica)
var AST2015seas10 = AST2015seasclip.multiply(100)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [ee.Image.multiply()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagemultiply) with a numerical input is fine, because the Earth Engine Javascript API automatically creates an image object.

In other words

```js
var AST2015seas10 = AST2015seasclip.multiply(100)
```

is equivalent to

```js
var AST2015seas10 = AST2015seasclip.multiply(ee.Image(100))
```

Comment: Nice but undocumented feature? The API link you gave and the doc do not mention this...